# how to change sqoop import temporary directory

Tags: apache, mapreduce, hdfs, sqoop, temp

sqoop import ...

by default puts all data into a temporary table directory before it ships it to target_directory. And in my case this temporary directory is defaulted to hdfs:///user/ directory. How do I change this to another hdfs directory ?

I tried doing the following but dint work. It still creates the temp directory in the hdfs:///user/ directory

sqoop import -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.am.staging-dir=hdfs://projects/ -Dmapreduce.jobtracker.staging.root.dir=hdfs://projects/ -Dhadoop.tmp.dir=hdfs://projects/ .....

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try using --temporary-rootdir to specify your hdfs location for your temp directory.

Thanks